# Duplicating shape with linked macro

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to automate a table to live calculate some values and have it prepared to add rows in the future. The simple item I'd like to add to this table is a '+' & '-' symbol (shape or image) linked to a macro which can change a value in another column. Doing this once is quite simple, but I'd like my population macro to essentially copy/paste the shape, along with its macro, linked to the next row.

For example:
a. Plus sign with macro assigned exists in A1 to click increases the value in B1 by 1
b. initiating another macro would copy/paste the image from A1 to A2, and the assigned macro should increase the value in B2

So far, I've been able to copy/paste the image, but unfortunately, all this does is enable both images to increase the value in B1.

Any ideas or possibilities if this is possible at all?

This is part of the code:
For the sake of the inquiry here, let's assume that there is working macro on the shape "Plus 50" which increases the value in B1 by an increment of 1.

```
For i = 1 to 50
   ActiveSheet.Shapes("Plus 50").Copy
   Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial
Next i
```

Incremental macro for reference.

```
Sub Plus 50_Click()
   Dim a As Integer
   a = Cells(1, 2)
   Cells(1, 2) = a + 1
End Sub
```

Would love any help on this at all, it would drastically speed up my excel sheet as I'm currently using a bunch of scrollbars that are taking a lot of time to load.

Thank you!

Comment: Well for starters, `Sub Plus 50_Click()` isn't syntactically valid, so it wouldn't even compile. For the sake of the inquiry here, could you post the actual code that you're using?

Comment: One way I can think of is for you to have a generic *procedure*. This procedure will be called by all your shapes. You will just have to determine what shape called the procedure. You can either: 1) Assign a name that will relate the shape to the cell you want to manipulate. 2) Get the coordinates of the shape (top, left) to distinguish which cell to manipulate.

Comment: @comintern that code did function the way I needed it to for one picture only.

Comment: @L42 that k you for this! I was thinking along those lines as well, but the issue is that I don't know how to go about generating a new picture, assigning a new macro to it, and linking a unique cell to each one... That's my challenge.

Comment: @AbeM Finding that hard to believe - `Plus 50_Click` isn't a valid name for a `Sub`. VBA identifiers can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously wrote a module to add custom buttons to add/delete rows from a table. I have modified it slightly for your use case, to increment/decrement the value of a target cell. It's not exactly what you asked for because the buttons float to the right of the target cell, but its pretty close and you can modify the draw method to fit your use case.

[image]

The buttons draw on selection_change and are deleted if the selection is outside of the table (or target column). There is only ever 1 set of buttons - for my original use case we didn't want to balloon the file size with shapes (probably the same issue you are having with scroll bars.)

- You must be using a table on the target worksheet (i.e. listobject)
- There is an option in drawButtons() to restrict the buttons to a specific column - uncomment and add the correct column name if you want to use this.
- After adding the following code, just click anywhere in the table (or target table column) and the buttons will appear.

**Add this in your target worksheet module:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call drawButtons(Target)
End Sub
```

**Add a code module and paste the following:**

```
Option Explicit

'Author:        Valon Miller
'Description:   This module draws custom increment and decrement
'               buttons on a list object that is intersected by the
'               supplied target range.
'Usgage:        Simply Call drawButtons(Target) from the
'               selection_Change event of any worksheet.

Private Const btnDiameter As Integer = 21
Private Const btnPadding As Integer = 3
Private btnLeft As Integer

Public Sub drawButtons(Target As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Dim btnTop As Integer

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objrow As ListRow

    Dim appScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim appCalculation As XlCalculation
    Dim appEnableEvents As Boolean

    On Error GoTo uhoh

    With Application
        'Remember Settings
        appScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        appCalculation = .Calculation
        appEnableEvents = .EnableEvents
        'Modify Settings
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set sh = Target.Parent

    'delete buttons if they exist
    deleteButtons sh

    'Check if the target intersects a DataBodyRange
    Set objrow = Range_getListRow(Target)
    If objrow Is Nothing Then GoTo getout

    'Uncomment to restrict the buttons to appear only when a specificed column is selected, by name
    'If Intersect(Target, objrow.Parent.ListColumns("Column1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then GoTo getout

    'Derive the target range of the buttons
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, objrow.Range)
    Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count)

    'Initialize Position Variables
    btnTop = rng.Top + ((rng.Height - btnDiameter) / 2)
    btnLeft = rng.Left + 3 + IIf(Range_getValidationType(rng.Cells(1, -1)) = 3, 16, btnPadding)

    'Draw Increment Button
    getNewButton sh, "IncrementButton", "+", "add_Click", btnLeft, btnTop, btnDiameter, msoShapeStylePreset37

    'Draw Decrement Button
    getNewButton sh, "DecrementButton", ChrW(&H2212), "sub_Click", nextLeft, btnTop, btnDiameter, msoShapeStylePreset37

getout:

    With Application
        'Restore Settings
        .ScreenUpdating = appScreenUpdating
        .Calculation = appCalculation
        .EnableEvents = appEnableEvents
    End With

    Exit Sub

uhoh:

    On Error Resume Next

    deleteButtons sh

    GoTo getout

End Sub

'************************************************************
'*                     Custom Methods                       *
'************************************************************

Private Function nextLeft() As Integer
    btnLeft = btnLeft + btnDiameter + btnPadding
    nextLeft = btnLeft
End Function

Private Function getNewButton(sh As Worksheet, strName As String, strCaption As String, macro As String, _
    intLeft As Integer, intTop As Integer, intDiameter As Integer, shpStyle As MsoShapeStyleIndex) As Shape

    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, intLeft, intTop, intDiameter, intDiameter)

    With shp

        .name = strName
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = strCaption
        .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
        .TextEffect.FontSize = 15
        .OnAction = macro
        .Placement = xlFreeFloating
        .shapeStyle = shpStyle

        'msoShapeStylePreset    Theme
        '---------------------------------
        'msoShapeStylePreset36  Black
        'msoShapeStylePreset37  Light Blue
        'msoShapeStylePreset38  Orange
        'msoShapeStylePreset39  Grey
        'msoShapeStylePreset40  Yellow
        'msoShapeStylePreset41  Dark Blue
        'msoShapeStylePreset42  Green

    End With

End Function

Private Sub deleteButtons(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim buttonNames() As String
    buttonNames = Split("IncrementButton,DecrementButton", ",")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each shp In sh.Shapes
        If Array_containsValue(buttonNames, shp.name) Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
End Sub

'************************************************************
'*                          Events                          *
'************************************************************

Public Sub add_Click()
    Dim newRecord As ListRow
    Dim objList As ListObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape

    On Error GoTo uhoh

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set shp = getShapeByName("IncrementButton", , sh)
    Set rng = getShapeRange(shp).Offset(0, -1)
    Set objList = rng.ListObject

    'Do Stuff
    rng = rng + 1

    Exit Sub

uhoh:

    MsgBox "Oops, unable to increment!", vbCritical, "Uhoh"

End Sub

Public Sub sub_Click()
    Dim selectedRecord As ListRow
    Dim objList As ListObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape

    On Error GoTo uhoh

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set shp = getShapeByName("DecrementButton", , sh)
    Set rng = getShapeRange(shp).Offset(0, -1)
    Set objList = rng.ListObject

    'Do Stuff
    rng = rng - 1

    Exit Sub

uhoh:

    MsgBox "Oops, unable to decrement!", vbCritical, "Uhoh"

End Sub

'************************************************************
'*                     Generic Methods                      *
'************************************************************

Private Function Array_isEmpty(arr As Variant)
' This function returns true if array is empty

  Dim l As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  l = Len(Join(arr))
  If l = 0 Then
    Array_isEmpty = True
  Else
    Array_isEmpty = False
  End If

  If Err.Number > 0 Then
      Array_isEmpty = True
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Private Function Array_containsValue(myArray As Variant, item As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Array_isEmpty(myArray) Then Array_containsValue = False: Exit Function
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If item = myArray(i) Then Array_containsValue = True: Exit Function
    Next i
    Array_containsValue = False
End Function

Private Function getListObjectByName(strName As String) As ListObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
            If tbl.name = strName Then Set getListObjectByName = tbl: Exit Function
        Next tbl
    Next sh
    Set getListObjectByName = Nothing
End Function

Private Function Range_getListRow(Target As Range) As ListRow
    'Check if target intersects with a list object
    If Not Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then
        'Check if the list object has a DataBodyRange
        If Not Target.ListObject.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            'Check if the first row of the target range is in the DataBodyRange
            If Not Intersect(Target.Rows(1), Target.ListObject.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                'Return ListRow that intersects with the first row in the target range
                Set Range_getListRow = Target.ListObject.ListRows(Target.Rows(1).Row - Target.ListObject.Range.Row)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'No intersect, return nothing
    Set Range_getListRow = Nothing
End Function

Private Function Range_getValidationType(rng As Range) As Integer
    'Name                   Value   Description
    'xlValidateInputOnly    0       Validate only when user changes the value.
    'xlValidateWholeNumber  1       Whole numeric values.
    'xlValidateDecimal      2       Numeric values.
    'xlValidateList         3       Value must be present in a specified list.
    'xlValidateDate         4       Date values.
    'xlValidateTime         5       Time values.
    'xlValidateTextLength   6       Length of text.
    'xlValidateCustom       7       Data is validated using an arbitrary formula.
    Dim t As XlDVType
    On Error GoTo uhoh
    Range_getValidationType = rng.Validation.Type
    Exit Function
uhoh:
    Range_getValidationType = -1
End Function

Private Function getShapeByName(nm As String, Optional inWb As Workbook, Optional inSh As Worksheet) As Shape
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim mySheets As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo uhoh

    'Get sheets to search
    Set wb = IIf(inWb Is Nothing, ThisWorkbook, inWb)
    Set mySheets = New Collection
    If inSh Is Nothing Then
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            mySheets.Add sh
        Next sh
    Else
        mySheets.Add inSh
    End If

    'Search for shape
    For i = 1 To mySheets.Count
        For Each shp In mySheets(i).Shapes
            If shp.name = nm Then Set getShapeByName = shp: Exit Function
        Next shp
    Next i

uhoh:

    Set getShapeByName = Nothing

End Function

Private Function getShapeRange(shp As Shape) As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = shp.Left + (shp.Width / 2)
    y = shp.Top + (shp.Height / 2)
    Set getShapeRange = Range_getByCoordinate(shp.Parent, x, y)
End Function

Private Function Range_getByCoordinate(sh As Worksheet, x As Integer, y As Integer) As Range
    Dim nCol, nRow As Range
    For Each nCol In sh.Columns
        If nCol.Left < x And nCol.Left + nCol.Width > x Then
            For Each nRow In sh.Rows
                If nRow.Top < y And nRow.Top + nRow.Height > y Then
                    Set Range_getByCoordinate = sh.Cells(nRow.Row, nCol.Column): Exit Function
                End If
            Next nRow
        End If
    Next nCol
End Function
```

Comment: that k you for this, I'll give it a try this evening as I'm at work as it may prove to be a simple work around. Ideally though, what I'd like to do, with code, is duplicate the +/- images you have in the image, one set for each row, and hav the buttons increase/decrease the values for their respective rows.

Comment: That could also be done, but then you are storing extra shapes. Depending on how many times you replicate them, that could make your file size very large. In this implementation the buttons follow the selected cell, i.e. if you select B3, the buttons will move next to that cell. If you want to keep all the buttons, then remove the delete calls and the selection_change event. Then you can call the drawButtons manually, or by some other macro OR just copy/paste the buttons on the sheet (after the first  set is drawn)

Comment: if you change the position of the buttons, (i.e. assuming you remove the delete and copy/paste buttons) you may need to update the target range derivation. currently it assumes that the target cell is 1 to the left of the cell that the buttons are in: Set rng = getShapeRange(shp).Offset(0, -1)